# Null Pointer Exception while trying to Bubble Sort

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bubble-sort

I'm writing a bubble sort method that involves tokenizing strings and I keep getting a mysterious null pointer exception.

The method takes an array of strings. Each string contains four tokens, last name, first name, social security number and age. The method needs to be able to sort by any of these tokens, so it breaks up each string into tokens, places the tokens in arrays, and then uses bubble sort to sort the tokens, rearranging each string in the array based on the token sorting.

The error occurs when I attempt to split the second string into tokens and save it to an array.

Here's the code.

```
            for (int i=0; i< array.length;i++) {


              String s1 = sortedArray[i];
              String s2 = sortedArray[i+1];

              String[] holdingArray1;
              String[] holdingArray2;

              holdingArray1 = s1.split("\\s+");
              holdingArray2 = s2.split("\\s+");



              int result = holdingArray1[0].compareTo(holdingArray2[0]);



              if (result > 0)
              {

                  sortedArray[i] = s2;
                  sortedArray[i+1] = s1; 
              }


              System.out.println(sortedArray[i]);
              System.out.println(sortedArray[i+1]);
            }
```

Comment: Show us the stack trace. The stack trace will give the exact line number that's causing the `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 3):

`i` may be less than array.length but `i+1` may not be. You're assuming there's `i+1` elements when you've only checked that there are `i` elements. Hence, `i+1` goes to `null` and you cannot `.split` `null`.

Comment: To be more precise, he is actually cheking the size of `array` but he accesses `sortedArray` which seems to have been initialized to an array of `null`, hence the NPE. If `i+1` was bigger than `sortedArray.length` then he would get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException? The error could even be caused by s1.split

Answer (score 0):

You need to do loop while less than array.length-1 since you are doing sortedArray[i+1].

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++)
{
  // logic
}
```

Here is a full bubble sort algorithm example.

```
    public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] arr, Boolean descending)
    {
         Boolean finished = false;

         while (!finished)
         {
             Boolean held = false;
             int hold;

             for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++)
             {
                  int curr = arr[i];
                  int next = arr[i+1];
                  Boolean test = curr > next;
                  if (descending) test = curr < next;

                  if (test)
                  {
                     held = true;
                     hold = next;
                     arr[i] = hold;
                     arr[i+1] = curr;
                  }             
             }

             if (!held) finished = true;
          }

          return arr;
     }
```